# How to change table columns name's prefix?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this below,

```
Field           Type            Collation           Attributes  Null    Default

cde_id          int(10)         No                  0                               
cde_title       varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Yes         NULL                                 
cde_content     mediumtext      utf8_general_ci     Yes                 NULL                                 
pg_id           varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Yes         0                                
cde_created     timestamp                                       No      0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

But I want to change the columns name's prefix from 'cde' to 'code'.

I use this query to change the name,

```
ALTER TABLE root_page_embed_codes
CHANGE cde_id code_id int(10)
```

Then I find that it is not dynamic enough because the column `types` are different from one to another and I have a `foreign key` - `pg_id` as well.

Any query method that I can use to change the prefix in a easier way?

Comment: Remove constraint, rename columns, add constraint.

Comment: Also, from what I recall (of my admittedly limited knowledge), isn't it usually best practices to use 'prefixes' only when it's a foreign key?  The 'prefix' should show up when referencing the _table_ (as in, `code.id = 1`, not `code.code_title = 'M'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An int in mysql is an int, always. The `(10)` portion is merely a hint to MySQL as to how many digits it should display. Regardless if whether you want 1 digit or 10, it's still going to be the same integer value definition internally.

What exactly do you mean, "not dynamic enough"? Changing the cde_id field's name won't affect pg_id field in any way.

---

followup: You can chain multiple field changes in a single alter query:

```
ALTER TABLE root_page_embed_codes CHANGE cde_id code_id int, cde_content code_content mediumtext, cde_created code_created timestamp
```

You can't get around having to specify the "new" field type, however, as MySQL is not smart enough to realize you're just renaming the field and not wanting to change anything BUT the name. There's no "rename" for fields as there is for tables and databases, unfortunately.

Comment: 1. I have other table columns I have to change. 2. cde_title       varchar(255) and cde_id  int(10) are different types - CHANGE cde_id code_id int(10) only apply to int(10). so when I want to change cde_title I have to change the query to varchar(255) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not care about dependent FK when field is being renamed. As Luc M suggested - you should recreate the FK.

Also, you can try to rename this field in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (Express Edition):

1. Select field in the Database Explorer
2. Rename it (press F2 or select Rename in popup menu)
3. Click on 'Refactor' button in a message box. It will rename selected field and recreate all related foreign keys.